# Looking for a rigorous way of showing that the two random variables $x$ and $y$ are not independent

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $x$ and $y$ be two random variables.

Suppose $m$ is a random variable that is independent of $x$ and has the following distribution:

$$\text{Pr}(m = 1|x) = 0.5,$$ $$\text{Pr}(m = -1|x) = 0.5.$$

Let $y$ be given by: $$y= \left\{ \begin{array}{lcc}
             0  & \text{if   } x\geq0 \\
             \\ m & \text{if   } x<0 \\
             \\ 
             \end{array}
   \right.$$

To show that $x$ and $y$ are not independent, can I use a more rigorous method other than just observing that it's the way $y$ is defined that clearly makes it dependent on $x?$

I wanted to use these kinds formula for no independence: $f(x,y) \neq f(x)f(y)$ or $f(y|x) \neq f(y)$.

Given the information, is it possible to even find $f(x)?$ I think it's possible to find $f(y|x)$ and $f(y)$ given the information, but not sure how they would be different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not enough information to prove that $x$ and $y$ are not independent. If $x$ is always positive or always negative, $y$ is independent of $x$ (being in the first case a constant and in the second case given by $m$, which is independent of $x$).

Comment: How do I show that they are dependent?

Comment: @OGC: Sorry, there was a "not" missing in the answer; I've added it. You can't show that they're dependent because they may not be, as explained in the answer.

Comment: What about this case though? $$\text{ Pr} (y=1|x) = \left\{\begin{matrix}
0 \text{    if  } x \geq 0\\ 
0.5 \text{   if  } x<0
\end{matrix}\right.$$

Doesn't this show that $x$ and $y$ are not independent?

Comment: @OGC: I don't understand the question; please elaborate.

Comment: Made an edit above.

Comment: @OGC: Where? I don't see any edit.

Comment: Let's look at this definition:

$$\text{ Pr} (y=1|x) = \left\{\begin{matrix}
0 \text{    if  } x \geq 0\\ 
0.5 \text{   if  } x<0
\end{matrix}\right.$$

Doesn't this show that $x$ and $y$ are not independent? Btw $x$ and $y$ are two random variables.

Comment: @OGC: I don't see how it does. This minimalistic style of communication is rather inefficient. Please explain in a complete exposition of your arguments from premise to conclusion why you believe that it does.

Comment: In your answer, for the second case, why do you think that $m$ is independent of $x$? I think $m$ is dependent on $x$ from the definition of $m$, and from the definition it follows that $y$ is not independent of $x$.

Comment: @OGC: $m$ is independent of $x$, as you correctly stated yourself in the question.

Answer (score 2):

$x$ and $y$ can be independant, for example if $x$ is constant.

But if you have $P(x\geq 0)>0$ and $P(x\lt 0)>0$, you have:

$P(x\geq 0,y=1)=0\neq P(x\geq 0)P(y=1)$